# How in liferay's tabs element control which tab to open

Tags: java, tabs, liferay, portlet, jsr286

In liferay's tabs, liferays version is 6, element, how to control which tab to open, for example, if I go from one tab to another .jsp page, and return back, I need to be opened, the tab, from which I leave page?
In tabs element I use sections.

Comment: You seriously need to reframe the question and make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Liferay? If 6 than you use param and value of tabs taglib

So

```
<liferay-ui:tabs names="Tab 1,Tab 2" tabsValues="tab1,tab2" param="tab" value="tab2" url0="<%= tab1URL %>" url1="<%= tab2URL %>" />
```

would set second tab active